# Does waiting for completion blocks cause leaks?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

Let us say that I have a method:

```
func getData(id:Int, completion: (object: object, error: Error?) -> ()){

        // some code

        let error = ErrorParser.parseData(data!)

        if error?.statusCode <= 200 {
            // do sth
        }
        else {
            completion(object: object, error: error)
        }

    }

}
```

My question is, what happens when I call this method from another class and the completion block is never called (the calling class never gets the block returned)? Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the part you've skipped in `// some code`.
Let's imagine you are using some 3rd party lib that is performing async request:

```
func getData(id:Int, completion: (object: object, error: Error?) -> ()){
    MyLibrary.doRequest(id: id) { data in
        let error = ErrorParser.parseData(data!)
        if error?.statusCode <= 200 {
            // do sth
        }
        else {
            completion(object: object, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are passing a new closure (let's name it `B`) as a parameter to `MyLibrary.doRequest` method. And your `completion` parameter is captured by the `B` closure, and won't be released until this closure is released.
Then MyLibrary stores a strong reference to `B` closure somewhere and *most likely* it will release `B` closure after the request is completed (or failed) and the `B` closure is executed.

Alternatively you can have some synchronous code here:

```
func getData(id:Int, completion: (object: object, error: Error?) -> ()){
    let data = OtherLib.loadDataFromDisk(id)
    let error = ErrorParser.parseData(data!)
    if error?.statusCode <= 200 {
        // do sth
    }
    else {
        completion(object: object, error: error)
    }
}
```

In this case, your completion block will be released after function returns.